# Sort References Yearly?

Tags: bibtex, sorting

I need to Sort my references yearly, right now i have tried unsrt, plain. both of them are not working.  I have written my bib file according to year though. All i need is to have my references sorted in yearly order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times} 


\begin{document}
 This is the example\cite{pena2015galean} and then this one\cite{ostergaard2010diagnosing}. Thanks \cite{pena20galean}

\pagebreak
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

if this is my bib file.

```
@inproceedings{pena2015galean,
  title={Galean: Visualization of Geolocated News Events from Social Media},
  author={Pe{\~n}a-Araya, Vanessa and Quezada, Mauricio and Poblete, Barbara},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 38th International ACM SIGIR Conference on Research and Development in Information Retrieval},
  pages={1041--1042},
  year={2015},
  organization={ACM}
}

@inproceedings{pena20galean,
  title={xxx},
  author={yyyy},
  booktitle={zzzzz},
  pages={1041--1042},
  year={2009},
  organization={ACM}
}

@article{ostergaard2010diagnosing,
  title={Diagnosing the online information search behavior of commercial airline travelers},
  author={{\O}stergaard, Stine and M{\"o}ller, L{\'a}ra},
  year={2010}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you in fact using the `biblatex` package (i.e. `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`), your mention of `unsrt` and `plain` would indicate that you're not using it. Or is it an option to switch to using `biblatex`?

Comment: No, I am not, i m working in Texmaker

Comment: You have the `sorting=ynt` (year-name-title) option of `biblatex`.

Comment: \bibliographystyle{sorting=ynt}
I have to it like this ?
Or do i need to include this package?

Comment: Should *all* entries in the bib file, or just a subset of the available entries, be shown in the bibliography?

Comment: All entries shouldbe shown

Comment: Texmaker is an editor (the program you write the code in), `biblatex` is a package for handling bibliographies (like `times` in `\usepackage{times}` is a package that changes the font). For some info on how to use `biblatex`, see e.g. [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509) and [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091). (This is just for information, I'm not saying that you must do it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've indicated that all entries in the bib file are already sorted chronologically. If, moreover, *all* entries are to be shown in the formatted bibliography, you may achieve your objective by using the `unsrt` bibliography style and issuing the instruction

```
\nocite{*}
```

immediately after `\begin{document}`. Of course, use `\cite` instructions throughout the body of the document to generate the desired citation call-outs.

After changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, be sure to rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: It doesnt show my references now

Comment: Can you please check again, i have edited the question

Comment: Do you still have `\cite` statements?